# Safe MySQL queries in vbscript

Tags: mysql, vbscript

Im doing some MySQL operations in vbscript and currently Im doing (not true vbscript code as I dont know the syntax off the top of my head):

```
Dim whereclause=textboxtext
$DBExecute("connectionstring","delete from table where column='"+query+"'")
```

Obviously this is VERY unsafe and almost destructive. Is there a MySQL function I can pass in that query to make it safer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic fairydust function to automatically make your statements harmless. A user that has permission to delete records will always be able to delete records.

If you're concerned about the way you *build* the statement (using string concatenation), now that's a whole other story. SQL injection can be mitigated via prepared statements (or [parameterized queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200190), as Microsoft calls them):

```vb
value = "..."
connectionString = "..."

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open connectionString

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM table WHERE column=?"

Set p = cmd.CreateParameter("@p", 200, 1, 255, value)
cmd.Parameters.Append p

cmd.Execute
```

Comment: Seems I cannot add parameters in this VBScript...Ive decided to make a virtual keyboard with only "safe" characters. Speakings of safe characters....